# How to get Gulp v4 watch observe file changes?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-4, gulp-task

Here is a very minimalistic example `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
function foo(done) {
    console.log('change');
    done();
}
function watchFiles() {
    console.log('starting watching...');
    gulp.watch('./gulpfile.js', gulp.series(foo));
};
gulp.task('watch-files', gulp.series(watchFiles));
```

A message "change" should be displayed on the console every time, when the `gulpfile.js` itself gets edited. But it doesn't work. I get the initial message "starting watching..." and the Gulp info about starting the task displayed.

```
$ gulp watch-files
[[[00:07:48] Using gulpfile /var/www/.../my-app/gulpfile.js
[00:07:48] Starting 'watch-files'...
[00:07:48] Starting 'watchFiles'...
starting watching...
```

But changes on the defined file to be observed (the `gulpfile.js`) are ignored, so no further messages are being displayed.

**What causes the issue and how to fix it and get the `watch`ing working?**

Comment: I pasted your code into a test and it worked.  This helped, otherwise it only runs once:  `function foo(done) {
  console.log('change');
  done();
}`  I just added the `done`s so it terminates the `foo` task.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Are you getting the output "change" every time, when you edit&save the `gulpfile.js`?

Comment: Yes.  it works as you expected.

Comment: I updated to code with `done`, so that it runs not only once, but on every change. So thanks again for your first comment. After it I tried running `gulp watch-files` in the same folder (meaning: with the same `gulpfile.js`) on my Windows 7 host system. There it's working. But it's still not working on my Ubuntu VirtualBox VM. So the environment seems to make the difference.